# Passing php data to a materialize modal

Tags: php, jquery, materialize

I am creating a confirmation pop up using [materializecss modals](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) to delete a specific record displayed on the page. Each record has its' own delete button to delete the question that the record is connected to. There php value `$questionCnt` is what refers to the record to delete.

I currently have a working method to delete the selected record, as long as it is not within a modal. My issue then comes when trying to pass the `$questionCnt` data to the modal. It keeps defaulting back to the first array value at index 0. I have commented this in my non-working code where exactly it happens at.

So instead of deleting the selected record it will delete the first record regardless of the selected record.

**Initialization**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
```

**Working Solution Without Modal**

```
    <form method="link" id="deleteQuestionForm" action="{{ url('api/question/deletequestiondata/') }}">
        <input type="hidden" id="questionToDelete" value=<?php echo '"' .  $questionData[$questionCnt] . '"'; ?> name = 'questionID'>
        <input type="hidden" id="urlForSurvey" value="{{$surveyName}}"  name = 'urlForSurvey'>
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" value="+" id="deleteQuestionButton" name="action" onclick="document.getElementById('deleteQuestionForm').submit();">
           <input type="submit" value="Delete Question">
        </button>
    </form>
```

**Non-Working Solution Within Modal**

```
@foreach($questiondata as $d)
<?php $questionCnt++; ?>
<div class="card white darken-1 hoverable">
   <div class="card-content black-text">
     <span class="card-title"><b>{{$d->questionTxt}}</b></span>
     <div class="card-action">
       <div class="button right">
        <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" >
           <i class="material-icons left">mode_edit</i>Edit
        </button>
        <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger red" href="#deletePopUP">
           <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
         </button>
         <?php echo $questionCnt ; ?>       <!-- Will print the correct index -->                                      
         <div id="deletePopUP" class="modal">
             <?php echo $questionCnt ; ?>   <!-- Will always print the first index -->
             <div class="modal-content">
                 <h4 align="center">Are you sure you wish to delete this question?</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer" align="center">
                 <form method="link" id="deleteQuestionForm" action="{{ url('api/question/deletequestiondata/') }}">
                     <input type="hidden" id="questionToDelete" value=<?php echo '"' .  $questionData[$questionCnt] . '"'; ?> name = 'questionID'>
                     <input type="hidden" id="urlForSurvey" value="{{$surveyName}}"  name = 'urlForSurvey'>
                     <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" value="+" id="deleteQuestionButton" name="action" onclick="document.getElementById('deleteQuestionForm').submit();">
                         <input type="submit" value="Delete Question">
                     </button>
                 </form>
                 <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">No, Return
                 </a>
              </div>
           </div>                                        
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
 </div>@endforeach
```

Comment: i think there is a piece missing in this question - i detect there must be a loop.  also, it's odd that we aren't given the values which are in `$questionData`

Comment: Really the only data that concerns the deletion is the `$questionCnt` which  there is just a for loop that displays each record on a card. I will add the loop for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue has been resolved.**
In order to pass the php value into the modal is to add it to the `href`of both the button that activates the modal and adjust the `id` of the modal tag.

**Code that was changed to resolve the issue**

```
<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger red" 
                  href="#deletePopUP<?php echo $questionCnt?>">
    <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
</button> 

<!-- Are you sure prompt -->
<div id="deletePopUP<?php echo $questionCnt?>" class="modal">
   <div class="modal-content"> 

<!-- Rest of modal content stayed the same -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm still curious what the array `$questionData` looks like (has in it)...`die('<pre>'.print_r($questionData, 1));` would solve my curiosity.

Nevertheless there is a minor error in

```
 <input type="hidden" id="questionToDelete" value=<?php echo '"' .  $questionData[$questionCnt] . '"'; ?> name = 'questionID'>
```

which could be the root of your problem.  You see, you are looping over `$questiondata` **NOT** `$questionData` (note the case sensitivity here).  Moreover, since you've set the current loop to `$d` in your `foreach` you should be using it like (or something like) this (i can't say for sure since you're holding the data contents of `$questiondata` as a secret, so far:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="questionToDelete" value="<?php echo $d['id']; ?>" name="questionID">
```

(I also cleaned up some quoting to make it more legible).